# John the ripper(kali linux) cant load hashes

Tags: john-the-ripper

I am trying to crack a md5 hash using a word list with john the ripper i used the following command:

```
john --format=raw-md5 --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt.gz /root/md5.txt
```

And i always get the following error:

```
**Using default input encoding: UTF-8**

**"No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)"**
```

The word list I'm using is rockyou.txt and the md5 hash is this

```
8AFA847F50A716E64932D995C8E7435A
5F4DCC3B5AA765D61D8327DEB882CF99
8621FFDBC5698829397D97767AC13DB3
F306109E6F069BCA5191DEB9B03359E2
F78900129CE480FC150F9B84D73B03F2
```

EDIT: I used small letters instead of capital letters for the hashes and i got this error

```
Warning: no OpenMP support for this hash type, consider --fork=2
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
0g 0:00:00:00 DONE (2019-10-20 13:15) 0g/s 501275p/s 501275c/s 1002KC/s G=ݟ�\����&��K(�p�#��W����KY�..R��4�^o��R��)����-�lQ�{�v{AC�����
Session completed
```

Comment: Did you read the FAQ?

Comment: i tried unshadowing the file and also deleted the john.pot file and i still get the same error

Comment: https://sgros.blogspot.com/2018/07/cracking-raw-md5-hashes-with-john-ripper.html - *"It turned out that John __doesn't support capital letters__ in hash value! "*

Answer (score 2):

Your wordlist is in compressed .gz format.

```
--wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt.gz
```

Uncompress it first.

```
--wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt
```

I copied your hash to my box.

```
kali@kali:$ cat hash.txt
8AFA847F50A716E64932D995C8E7435A
5F4DCC3B5AA765D61D8327DEB882CF99
8621FFDBC5698829397D97767AC13DB3
F306109E6F069BCA5191DEB9B03359E2
F78900129CE480FC150F9B84D73B03F2
kali@kali:$
```

Check the supported format

```
kali@kali:$ john --list=formats | tr , '\n' | grep -i md5
 md5crypt
 md5crypt-long
 asa-md5
 dmd5
 krb5pa-md5
 net-md5
 md5ns
 PBKDF2-HMAC-MD5
 pix-md5
 Raw-MD5
 Raw-MD5u
 SunMD5
tcp-md5
 HMAC-MD5
kali@kali:$
```

Try again ... voilà

```
kali@kali:$ john --show --format=Raw-MD5 hash.txt 

<Cracked password removed>

5 password hashes cracked, 0 left
kali@kali:$
```